# To Int function causes error in Xcode 7 beta

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am creating a project using swift that reads a `textfield` and converts the string to an int. XCode 6 allows me to use the `textfield.text.toInt()` function, but xcode 7 beta says that the function is not available. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: This change is explicitly *documented* in the Xcode 7 beta release notes: "String.toInt() has been renamed to a failable Int(String) initializer" ...

Answer (score 2):

This function has been removed, use the initializer

```
Int(textfield.text)
```

instead